# What does $k$ stand for here?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, notation, physical-constants

We know that diode equation is 
$$I_d=I_S(e^{V_d/nV_T}-1)$$
where $V_T$ is the thermal voltage acquired, given by $V_T=kT/q$. But what does this $k$ stand for? The value of $k$ is given as $1.38 \times 10^{-23}\,{\rm J/K}$ with $T$ the temperature and $q$ the charge of an electron.

Comment: [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant)

Comment: You could've just put the value into the google search

Comment: or just googled 'diode equation' and find a [Wikipedia entry with that title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation) and the terms explicitly defined in the introduction.

Answer (score 2):

It stands for Boltzmann's constant. I see it relatively often as $k_{b}$ or $k_{B}$ and I always write it like that because that way it can not be confused with the wave number $k$. For further info see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant